# PHP <b> replace to &lt;b&gt;

Tags: php

If i write to input `<b>` in database write `&lt;b&gt;` . Help.

Input code :

```
$aprasymas =  htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aprasymas']));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO prekes (pavadinimas, kaina, aprasymas, nuotrauka, cover, kategorija, kiekis) VALUES ('$pavadinimas', '$kaina', '$aprasymas', '$nuotrauka', '$cover', '" . kategorijaid($kategorija) . "', '$kiekis')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You need to understand how escaping works.  Calling `htmlentities` for a database makes no sense.

Comment: DO NOT use mysql functions. They are deprecated and not safe. Go for mysqli or other _PDO  - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: I have seen so many questions where people want to insert HTML into MySQL, it makes my head spin. HTML is HTML, MySQL is MySQL. You should handle formatting in the output; two different animals altogether. A database is meant for data, not for formatting purposes.

Comment: Btw;  even `mysql_real_escape_string()` is prone to injection https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/1415724 - best you use the mysqli or PDO api with a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

because `htmlentities` converts `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`

a better approach will be storing the data into the database in it's *raw* form - `<b>` in your case, then you do the proper escaping before submitting the data for it's final destination depending on the destination context.

if you are going to put the data into an HTML document then use `htmlentities`

```
echo "<td>".htmlentities($databaseResult['aprasymas'])."</td>"
```

building a url ?

```
header("Location: /page?aprasymas=" .urlencode($databaseResult['aprasymas']));
exit;
```

But, if you converted the raw data and store it in the database, then you are going to lose the original data.

Comment: *"a better approach will be storing the data into the database in it's raw form"* - [This is what I told the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225928/php-b-replace-to-ltbgt#comment77418880_45225928). I feel that storing HTML in a database is just a bad idea. `htmlentities()` is meant to be used during "output". They probably think that that function helps to prevent  an sql injection, which it doesn't. Even `mysql_real_escape_string()` is prone to injection https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/1415724